# Sony Vaio crashes once a day on average

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, bsod, sony-vaio

A user had a Sony T series laptop (SVT1311CGXS) that is out of warranty but is still a nice laptop.  The problem is that it starts running super slow for 30 seconds and then reboots.  It's running Windows 7 x64 SP1.  I did all the driver updates available through the Sony update utility including a BIOS update.  I wiped the system and did a clean install of Windows 7.  I've disabled automatic system restart and enabled minidumps but when it happens when I'm away from the computer I come to a black screen with white text Operating system not found. The minidumps are also not created. To get the system to boot up I unplug the power adapter, turn off and back on.  It then proceeds to boot like normal. CrystalDisk Info says the SSD is healthy. I've ran the Sony hardware diagnostics and they come back clear.

I was able to once capture a shot of the BSOD.
KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR

STOP 0x0000007A (0xFFFFF6FC4 0008198,0XFFFFFFFFC...)
volmgrx.sys - address...

Comment: check your HDD for issues

Comment: I'm going to swap out the SSD and see if my problems go away. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/receving-0x000000f4-and-0x0000007a-blue-screen/725b2bb4-2f80-43be-b8d6-d2179ba505b8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSD swap fixed the problem.

I think what's most telling that it's a drive issue was the fact that the machine wasn't able to write a mini dump when it crashed.  If it was a component not related to the drive it should have been able to write those mini dumps.  Drive testing tools commonly report false negatives but less frequently false positives.

Answer (score 0):

according to [EightForums](http://www.eightforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/50063-bsod-kernel_data_inpage_error-volmgrx-sys-3.html#post407388) in windows it is caused mostly by updates. Try uninstalling updates from last 2-3 weeks and you will see. also try running memory test to see if there is no issue with memory.

and lastly check if you are booting in EFI mode or legacy. legacy mode can cause this as well with some help from updates.

Comment: Please reference (with a link) your Google source to validate what you are claiming.

Comment: link:http://www.eightforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/50063-bsod-kernel_data_inpage_error-volmgrx-sys-3.html#post407388

Comment: The BIOS is a bear to get into (damn sony).  I've only successfully entered it once and I wasn't thinking about EFI then :/

Comment: I added your reference link to your answer for you. Since the reference is to a Windows 8 forum, is this answer relevant to Windows 7 (which is what the OP has)? If so, you need to state that, otherwise, it can be confusing.